# EcSlidingViewController disable gester all together

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using EcSlidingViewController version 1, and I am trying to disable the gesture all together. I just need the button to slide view controllers in and out. I have found a few links here but they were all for disabling the tableview swipe to delete.Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

In the viewDidLoad comment out this:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

to this

```
//[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

Be sure to comment out this in **each** view that you do not want it to recognize a gesture.